# opencv pkg-config configuration problem in ubuntu with fuerte

Tags: opencv, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After ros-fuerte installation in ubuntu 12.04, I am having problems to compile my opencv programs.
I am getting the following results:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_nonfree
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_photo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stitching
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ts
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videostab
```

I realised that ros-fuerte packages for ubuntu changes default pkg-config configuration file for opencv library, pointing to the files in the ros installation.

```
# pkg-config --cflags opencv
-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include 

# pkg-config --libs opencv 
-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

- Why is ros changing the default opencv configuration for compilation?
- Can't just use a different pkg-config configuration file such as ros-opencv.pc?
- And, in case the default configuration must be changed, why it is not compatible with previous opencv configurations?

**Update**

I have found the problem. The setup.sh script of ros-fuerte updates the variable that uses pkg-config to find the configuration files

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Now pkg-config gives preference to ROS configuration.

So the answer now is:
Is this really needed to be in the setup.sh script?

Maybe rosmake can set this variable when using pkg-config to configure the compilation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39014/opencv-pkg-config-configuration-problem-in-ubuntu-with-fuerte/) by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-07-17**:
Have you installed  `ros-feurte-vision-opencv` using `apt-get`?

**Comment by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) on 2012-07-17**:
Yes. I installed all ros fuerte using apt-get system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When pkg-config has to find your package, it looks for the right paths in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable. And the order of the paths in this variable actually matters. If you do:

> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

You are giving priority to the packages of ROS, because it is found first in the list of paths.

You can use the same to override the ROS package and use the standalone OpenCV. After sourcing the file /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh  you can add the path to the standalone OpenCV installation (note that I add the path in the left side of the variable):

> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/bin/opencv/lib/pkgconfig/:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}

If you want to change to ROS packages, just source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh again.

---

Originally posted by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) with karma: 126 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0